# Changing RootView controller Xamarin IOS app

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

My Xamarin IOS project uses a Storyboard. Its a tabbarcontroller app, I'd like to modify the number of tabs in my root UITabBarController.

You can't add or remove tabs if you crate the tabbarcontroller from a Storyboard. I'd like to replace the root view controller with one that is not created from the Storyboard. I'd still like the Storyboard for some of my other classes.

Instructions for creating an empty Xamarin project or removing the Storyboard from an Xamarin project using Visual Studio on the Mac do not work.

I think the new SceneDelegate removes the ability to set a root view controller in AppDelegate.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually , you don't need to delete the `Storyboard` . If you want to set the `RootViewController` in AppDelegate , check the following code.

#### in Appdelegate

the following code will work before iOS 13.0

```
public bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

   this.Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
   var MainViewController = new MyViewController();
   this.Window.RootViewController = MainViewController;
   this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

   return true;
}
```

And after iOS 13.0 , we should call the similar code in `SceneDelegate` , so add the following code to SceneDelegate at same time .

```
public void WillConnect (UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.

    this.Window = new UIWindow(new UIWindowScene(session,connectionOptions));
    var MainViewController = new MyViewController();
    this.Window.RootViewController = MainViewController;
    this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see  UIApplicationDelegate `GetConfiguration` instead).
}
```

In addition , if you want to change the RootViewController in run time (for example when click a button) .

We used Animation to make the process smooth

```
var MainController = new UITabBarController();
CATransition transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
transition.Duration = 0.3;
transition.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseOut);

UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController = MainController;
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, "Animation");
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I knew about the AppDelegate modification and I know that it was SceneDelegate that was messing things up, but I could not find the incantation to make it work. Now the code is obviously redundant - but working.

Comment: Now I notice that text input is disabled for my app after changing the rootViewController in SceneDelegate. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You could create a new thread with more details so that people can help you better .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677120/textfield-in-xamarin-ios-not-allowing-input

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side

Comment: Hey , your code is doing what it's entended to do , but typing in textfields doesnt work anymore using mac keyboard or simulator keyboard when I apply your ```willConnect ``` 
 function code.  Can you help please? @Lucas Zhang - MSFT

Comment: okay I found why I had this problem . I changed  ```this.Window = new UIWindow(new UIWindowScene(session,connectionOptions));``` from your ```willConnect``` function to ```Window = new UIWindow(scene as  UIWindowScene);```