# TextField in Xamarin IOS not allowing input

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I have an ios App created in Xamarin with Visual Studio on the Mac. I've modified SceneDelegate to load a UITabController that is *not* created on the Storyboard. I've done this to allow changing the number of tabs presented in some cases.

The UITabController is adding a View that is defined on the Storyboard. This view contains a TextField, this textfield does not allow text entry. When you tap it a keyboard does not appear.

Yes User Interaction Enabled is checked.

How can I fix this?
Thanks, Gerry

Comment: Did you put the TextFiled on the UIImageView ? You would better provide the code or share a sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: This is my custom UITabbarController class:
public class TabController : UITabBarController
{
public TabController()
{
UIViewController t1;

        t1 = new UIViewController();
        t1.Title = "Greeen";
        t1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;

        var story = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        UIViewController v1 = story.InstantiateViewController("ViewId");
        v1.Title = "First";

        var tabs = new UIViewController[] { v1, t1 };
        ViewControllers = tabs;
    }
}

Comment: This is my appdelegate code:
public bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
UIViewController vc = new TabController();
Window.RootViewController = vc;
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }

Comment: This is scene delegate:
[Export("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
public void WillConnect(UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
Window = new UIWindow(new UIWindowScene(session, connectionOptions));
UIViewController vc = new test4.TabController();
Window.RootViewController = vc;
Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
}

Comment: The UIViewController "ViewId" is a simple UIViewController from the Storyboard that contains a text input field. The clear button on the UITextField works, but the keyboard never pops up so that you can enter text.

The other weird thing is that the "ViewId" is still marked as initial view controller in the storyboard, and you cannot change that.
Sorry about the formatting.
Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: Check my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assign the UIScene (actually a UIWindowScene) to the WindowScene property of the Window , so improve the code in SceneDelegate.WillConnect like following :

```
Window = new UIWindow(scene as UIWindowScene);


UIViewController vc = new MyTabController();
Window.RootViewController = vc;

Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```