# Search Bar doesn't register input

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I created a MapView and a SearchBar in a .xib file. I loaded the xib file into a ViewController was testing it in the simulator. The MapView works as it should, but the SearchBar doesn't register any input. Whatever key I press on my keyboard, the SearchBar just shows my cursor and the placeholder text. I used the SearchBar in another project to see if it works there and it does. I can type whatever I want to in there.

I don't know why it doesn't work in my loaded .xib file. Doesn't it work in .xib? I also cleaned and rebuild everything and made sure that user interaction is enabled. I enabled it in code and Xcode.

Here are my attributes for the SearchBar from Xcode. I think everything is right but maybe it helps.

[image]

Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

I found out that I'm not only unable to make an input, but also can't add (or see) a scope bar to the SearchBar. Again, I could add it in another project but not in this current one. No matter if the scope bar is enabled or disabled, I can't see it when I click on the SearchBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a problem in my SceneDelegate. I still don't understand why and how this error occurred but I somehow missed *this* in my SceneDelegate:

```
this.Window = new UIWindow(scene as UIWindowScene);
```

If you are experiencing the same issue or want to know why, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60677120/textfield-in-xamarin-ios-not-allowing-input) another question I've found with the working solution